# Can use microdata on stars instead of a number in reviewRating?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, user-reviews

This is my HTML code for a review on a user.  The documentation for rating says you have to mark up a number like: `<span itemprop="reviewRating">5</span>`.  However, I only use stars and not a number so that is not applicable in my HTML.

```
<div class="review-card text-center" itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/482469078777667/picture?type=square" alt="" class="profile-img">
<div class="review-author">
<span class="ra-author" itemprop="author">Snehah Lama</span>
<ul class="rating-star">                                                                
<li><i class="material-icons">★</i></li>
<li><i class="material-icons">★</i></li>                   
<li><i class="material-icons">★</i></li>
<li><i class="material-icons">☆</i></li>
<li><i class="material-icons">☆</i></li>              
</ul>
</div>
<div class="review-content">
<p class="content-inner" itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor....</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Do I have change my whole HTML structure to accommodate a number that can be annotated, or is there another way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t want to display a structured data value on the page, you can use the `meta` element (if the value is a URL, you have to use the `link` element instead).

That said, if you have a [`Review`](http://schema.org/Review), specifying an integer as value for [`reviewRating`](http://schema.org/reviewRating) is not expected. The property expects a [`Rating`](http://schema.org/Rating) value, which can have the [`ratingValue`](http://schema.org/ratingValue) property.

**With showing the value,** the markup could look like this:

```html
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
  <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">3</span>/5
  </div>
</div>
```

**Without showing the value,** the markup could look like this:

```html
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
  <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="3">
    <span>★★★☆☆</span>  <!-- note that this is likely not accessible, the 'meter' element might be better -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**With the `meter` element,** the actual value (which gets used by Microdata) is hidden anyway:

```html
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
  <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
    <meter itemprop="ratingValue" value="3" min="0" max="5">★★★☆☆</meter>
  </div>
</div>
```

But Google’s [SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) doesn’t seem to work correctly: they use the `meter` element’s content instead of the content of the `value` attribute (which is [required by the Microdata spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#values)). Adding a `content` attribute with the same value fixes this in the SDTT.