# Can display:none CSS be used on a div with a rich snippet?

Tags: html, schema.org, rich-snippets, microdata, hidden-text

I'd like to use the following code:

```html
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <div>
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">[rating]</span> from
      <div style="display: none;" itemprop="bestRating">5</div>
      <span itemprop="ratingCount">[quantity]</span> reviews
    </div>
</div>
```

It's a typical 5-star rating system so displaying "5" is unnecessary.

Is `display:none` usable? If not, alternate suggestions are welcome.

I did try it in the structured data testing tool and it passed. However, I'm still worried that it may not work in the search engine.

Answer (score 2):

For such a purpose, the `meta` element can be used. It’s visually hidden by default.

```html
<meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
```

(For [representing a rating value](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/113984/17633) in HTML, you could also use the `meter` element, which allows setting the `min` and `max` with HTML attributes.)

For the **structured data**, it doesn’t matter whether the data is visible or not.
For **structured data consumers** like search engines, it might matter, though, as search engines do not want to fall for manipulations, and hiding data *could* be a manipulation.

But there are clear cases where there is no reason to assume that hiding the data could be misunderstood to be manipulation, and your example is one of those cases. The fact that 5 is the max value is likely indicated in some way to your readers (e.g., graphically), so providing this information within a `meta` element is just providing it in a different, machine-readable format.

(NB: If the max value is 5, you could omit the [`bestRating`](https://schema.org/bestRating) property, as 5 is assumed; but I would argue that it’s usually a good practice to provide it anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Google may consider this as spam in structured data. Check the following information from Google guides **[Manual Actions report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175)**:

> Structured data found on hidden content    Structured data found on
>   elements that are not visible to the user.

Don't do it.